# Spring security changing an logged user's role doesn't take effect immediately

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, roles

I'm using Spring Security 3.2. I can reload current user's authorizes dynamically after changing his roles with:

```
UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(dao.getEntity(User.class,currentUserService.getUserDetails().getUsername()));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

but it works only for current user. I want change other users (logged) roles and reload their authorizations dynamically with my admin user. I also use `SessionRegistry`, and write method for admin service:

```
  public void reloadUserAuthorizes(String username)
    {
        List<Object> loggedUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
        for (Object principal : loggedUsers)
        {
            if(principal instanceof UserDetailsImpl)
            {
                final UserDetailsImpl loggedUser = (UserDetailsImpl) principal;
                if(username.equals(loggedUser.getUsername()))
                {
                    List<SessionInformation> sessionsInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false);
                    if(null != sessionsInfo && sessionsInfo.size() > 0)
                    {
                        for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionsInfo)
                        {
                            sessionInformation.expireNow();
                            sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is executing successfully, and finds all logged users, and their sessions, but it doesn't take effect. A user which logged and granted authorizes, he keep his authorizations, even I expire his session.